# Solution of the Differential equation $ u'(t)=4u^{3/4}(t) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let u(t) be a continuously differentiable function taking nonnegative values for $t\gt 0$ and satisfying $ u'(t)=4u^{3/4}(t) $; $ u(0)=0.\; Then \\ 1. u(t)=0 \\2. u(t)=t^4. \\3. u(t)= \begin{cases} 0 \qquad \qquad for \;\;0\lt t\lt 1 \\ (t-1)^4 \qquad for \;\;t\ge 1. \end{cases}\\4. u(t)=\begin{cases} 0 \qquad \qquad  for \;\;0\lt t\lt 10 \\ (t-10)^4 \qquad for \;\;t\ge 10. \end{cases}  $

My Attempt: given equation $\frac{du}{dt}=4u^{3/4} \\$

By variable seperable method,

$\frac{du}{4u^{3/4}}=dt $

On integrating we get

$ u^{1/4}=t
\Rightarrow u=t^4 $ which gives option 2.

But i am not getting the other three solutions.
given that all the options are correct. thanks in advance.

Comment: this is the right solution

Comment: i don't know how to prove the remaining three options. given that all the options are correct

Comment: You're missing a constant btw.

Comment: Look in your analysis for the illegal operation "divide by zero".  Also "integrating" needs a $+C$.

Comment: by using the the given condition u(0)=0 the value of C becomes zero so directly i have the answer.

Comment: Not sure you got the idea (and Graubner's comment is misleading, as usual): actually, **all four functions are solutions**.

Comment: Actually this question is asked in csir net exam december 2015 and all the options are correct in the given key answers

Comment: Good. And can you prove that? If not, where is the obstacle?

Comment: If u(t)=t^4 then how do we get the option 1. u(t)=0?

Comment: @Priyanka If $u\equiv 0$, then $u'\equiv 0$ and $4u^{3/4}\equiv 0$, thus lhs=rhs. Similar for the other options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to work under the assumption that ODEs have **unique solutions**. **This is wrong** is general. One theorem on uniqueness of solutions $\dot x = f(t,x)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$, is Picard-Lindelöf which needs local Lipschitz continuity of $f$ with respect to $x$. Your ODE is one of these examples where this is not fulfilled and indeed (as you can check by differentiating all four function that you have) the solutions stop to be unique as soon as the reach the value $x=0$ (which is the only point where $f$ is not locally Lipschitz).

Answer (score 2):

Any function $u(t)=\max(0,t-c)^4$, $c\ge0$ is a solution, as it is a continuous differentiable function and its derivative $u'(t)=4\max(0,t-c)^3$ satisfies the differential equation. Your cases are the solutions for $c=\infty,0,1,10$.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attempting to solve the equation, you can plug the proposed solutions.

1. Is of course valid, $(0)'=0^4\land 0=0$.
2. and 3. and 4. $((t-c)^4)'=4((t-c)^4)^{3/4}$ for $t\ge c$ (and we already know that $0$ is fine elsewhere).

All these solutions are valid.

Comment: Yes it is correct. I thought I have to get all the solutions only by solving the equation. Thank you

Comment: The thing that is wrong in your resolution: you may not divide by $u$ when $u$ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Only $u(t)=t^{4}$ and $u(t)=0$ are solutions which satisfy both the initial condition and the condition to be continuously differentiable! All other functions satisfy the equation and the initial condition, however, they are not continuously differentiable.

Comment: Hem, the functions are differentiable to the third order ! Undue upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The integration should give
$u^{1/4}=t+c$ for any real $c$.

At $t=c$, $((t-c)^4)'=4(t-c)^3$
is zero so this is continuously differentiable.

Comment: This approach is unsatisfactory because 1., 3. and 4. are valid solutions, though they are not covered by the given expression.

Answer (score 0):

**A more rigorous resolution:**

From the given equation, we can infer that $u(t)\ge0$. Then provided $u(t)>0$, we may separate and

$$\frac14u^{-3/4}du=dt$$ gives

$$u^{1/4}=t+c,$$

$$u(t)=(t+c)^4.$$

With the initial condition $u(0)=0$, we have $c^4=0$ and the only solution seems to be $u(t)=t^4.$

---

But, the option $u(t)=0$ remains, and is also a solution.

What's more, we can have $u(t)=0$ in an interval $[0,c]$, $c>0$, then switch to $(t-c)^4$, without losing differentiability. It is not possible to switch back to $0$ later, because then $u>0$.

Comment: "A more rigorous resolution:" Sorry but is this a joke? I see no rigor here, only the reproduction of the wrong argument leading to "the" solution being $u(t)=t^4$, followed by an odd "oops" moment...

Comment: @did: you didn't read carefully. The key argument is $u(t)>0$.